# ataX softreset failed 1st fis failed after switching motherboard

Tags: ubuntu, hard-disk, sata

I got these messages for all drives after upgrading motherboard and processor from Intel to AMD

Happened on all 5 disks: ata1, ata14, ata2, ata5, ata6 (weirdly there's only 6 sata ports in the motherboard, but there's ata14?)

[image]

How to solve this? If possible without reinstall ubuntu

Already tried `libata.force=noncq` or `libata.force=nosrst` but still the same. Can boot thru recovery mode (`fsck` on all drives works fine) but not on normal mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, my old kernel parameter for Intel is the problem `pci=nomsi`, removing this flag on `/etc/default/grub` then `sudo update-grub`, then reboot solves my problem